# Custom UITableViewCell displaying blank

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have created a xib file and then created a class of tableViewCell. I have attached photos of how I have attached the outlets to the file. I am trying to assign values to the cells that are made during the tableview cell creation but the cells keep appearing blank once the app runs. Here are a few screenshots of my code and the xib file.
    [image]
    [image]
    [image]
    [image]
Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: delete the line: `cell=[[LeagueCell alloc] init];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dequeing a cell and then instantiating it again. Just remove the line where it says `cell = [[LeagueCell alloc] init];`

Answer (score 0):

Delete the line `cell=[[LeagueCell alloc] init];` 
and change the cell initialisation as follows:

```
cell = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LeagueCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting tags to the labels

```
  UILabel *name = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
  UILabel *position = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
  UILabel *score = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102];

  cell.name = [currentObject valueForKey:@"username"];
  //rest of the code similarly
```

Also put

```
  cell = [[LeagueCell alloc] init];
```

inside

```
   if (cell == nil) {

     cell = [[LeagueCell alloc] init];

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

put this code which is registering nib for you in `ViewDidLoad`

```
 UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"LeagueCell" bundle:nil];
[self.tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"LeagueCellCellIdentifier"];
```

Now , in `CellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
LeagueCell *pnCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"LeagueCellCellIdentifier"];

return pnCell;
```

Note: Use same CellIdentifier in `CellForRowAtIndexPath`  which you given in `ViewDidLoad`

Answer (score 0):

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

```
static NSString *cellidenfier=@"cell";
League *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidenfier];
if (cell==nil) {
    cell=[[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"League" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
}
return  cell;
```

}

Please make sure that file owner is has class NSObject and you custom cell had class of ur classname. Make a outlet from your custom class not with fileowner...